# CMake command is not recognized

Tags: windows, cmake

I have installed CMake and cmake.exe is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin`
 But when I run `call cmake %CMAKE_BUILD_OPTIONS%` through a bat file I am getting an error message

> 'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Should I set this path in environment variable?

Comment: Yes add to %PATH% or call C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['cmake' is not recognised as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176029/cmake-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: @usr1234567 For us average mortals, there is no `cmake`; just `.exe`s

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It resolved after adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin`  to environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: have done that but problem is, it only run when cmd/powershell is in admin privileges. I installed cmake with chocolaty

Answer (score 8):

Was able to resolve the issue by installing [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation) (on Windows 10) and running `choco install cmake`

Comment: very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

in case someone install the Windows C++ Build Tools / Visual Studio, check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69324180/10805680

Answer (score 0):

You can install `cmake` with the built-in windows package manager `winget` by running this in a command line application:

```
winget install cmake
```

You'll need to restart your command line application or open another tab for `cmake` to be accessible after that.