# error: command 'cmake' failed: No such file or directory

Tags: python, cmake, pyarrow, python-3.8, vaex

Getting error while installing vaex in Pycharm with Python3.8
I have installed below before running this on my Win-10 64-bit:

```
- cmake v3.15.3
- pep517 v0.8.1
- pip v19.3.1
```

Error logs:

```
running build_ext
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
-- Running cmake for pyarrow
cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe  -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g3tufyo5\pyarrow
error: command 'cmake' failed: No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly.
```

Any idea, what I am missing?

Comment: Is `cmake` in `%PATH%`? In what environment are you running the installation?

Comment: Sorry, I am new. I tried installing using pycharm and through command line. And in env variable, I can see this path.  
C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake command is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675150/cmake-command-is-not-recognized)

Comment: Thank you for the information but still having error.  I found cmake and added in environmental variable in PATH  
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin  


Now, getting different error:   
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.18362.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (project):
    Failed to run MSBuild command:
      MSBuild.exe
    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:
      The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: is `MSBuild.exe` in `%PATH%`? In what environment are you running the installation?

Comment: I can see MSBuild only in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and even after adding it in %PATH% and in env variable, it still failes. I am installing in venv environment.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help here. There is a lot of information missing, like what is the command you're running in first place (I guess it's something like `pip`?)? You should also not ask questions in comments. Edit your question or ask a new one. Please ask some search engine about the error message before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478492/cmake-failed-to-run-msbuild-command-msbuild-exe

Comment: Currently there are Python 3.8 wheels for Arrow available, it is probably better to currently use Python 3.7 and wait 1-2months for the 3.8 wheels to appear instead of struggling with CMake.

Answer (score 4):

Are you able to install CMake in your system?
I had the same issue and I used `pip3 install cmake`.

Answer (score -1):

pip3 install --upgrade pip

pip3 install cmake