# Emscripten can't find path to cmake

Tags: c++, llvm, emscripten, asm.js

[I've gone over the instructions several times](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html), looked in countless forums, and still can't resolve this issue.

I'm running Windows 10, and simply trying to install Emscripten. I've got Emscripten installed:

[image]

I run

```
# Fetch the latest registry of available tools.
emsdk update
```

followed by

```
# Download and install the latest SDK tools.
emsdk install latest
```

[image]

But it continues to throw the same warning about being unable to find the path to cmake.

I've downloaded and installed **cmake-3.3.2-win32-x86**. I cannot create the PATH from the installation though, because it says the file length is too long. odd, because it is installed here:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin*

I figured I could set the path myself, [as seen in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176029/cmake-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command). Therefore, I used this command after the image above:

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\";%PATH%
```

and have the same issue. I'm fresh out of ideas. Could it have to do with the fact that 64 bit versions of clang and the sdk are being installed, but Cmake only comes in 32bit flavor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quotes aren't needed in PATH environmental variables on Windows.

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\;%PATH%
```

Comment: That worked! I feel like an idiot. I spent so much time troubleshooting this (as seen above), only to discover that it was because I using quotes. Thank you again!