# age genderclassification using caffe in windows platform

Tags: java, image-processing, caffe, conv-neural-network

To achieve age and gender classification, i tried with the framework caffe.

1) i downloaded the caffemodel from the link http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/projects/cnn_agegender and later on downloaded the windows version (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) i maintained the dependencies Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 and cmake 3.6.3
the error i got is as follows

```
'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR: Configure failed
```

Please suggest the way forward. And please let me know the steps how to achieve age and gender classification.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['cmake' is not recognised as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176029/cmake-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: your windows doesn't know cmake, you have to add cmake's location to the PATH environment variable so windows knows that it should also look there for unknown executables

Answer (score 0):

After i installed visual studio 2015 and then created C++ project which implicitly downloaded C++ libraries. Able to run the **build_win** successfully.