# cmake is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: cmake

While running the command cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -T host=x64 -D ONNX=ON .. to create a visual studio solution of ELL in py36 environment of anaconda command prompt, am getting the error cmake is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Have you checked other questions with the same error message? E.g. that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176029/cmake-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['cmake' is not recognised as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176029/cmake-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

That means that cmake is either not installed or not on your "PATH".